# Кросскомпиляция deb-пакетов

Tags: ubuntu, debian, arm, orange-pi

Каким образом собрать пакет в ubuntu той же версии, но под другую архитектуру используя кросс-компилятор arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc?
Как модифицировать Makefile, чтобы вызывался кросс-компилятор вместо обычного?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для сборки пакетов в Debian существует стек утилит (каждая из которых вызывает следующие более низкоуровневые):

- pdebuild
- pbuilder
- apt-get, debuild
- dpkg-buildpackage
- dpkg-architecture, fakeroot, debian/rules
- dh, dh_...
- make, strip, dpkg-deb

Верхние четыре уровня позволяют указывать целевую архитектуру в аргументах запуска. Нижние уровни берут эту информацию из переменных окружения. Первые два собирают пакеты в изолированном окружении для проверки, что все зависимости сборки указаны. Они требуют много дисковой памяти и времени для подготовки окружения, ими стоит пользоваться перед выпуском вашего пакета в общее пользование. Для внутреннего использования наверно лучше подойдёт `dpkg-buildpackage`. Запуск из каталога исходников пакета (тот, в котором находится подкаталог *debian*):

```
dpkg-buildpackage -a armhf
```

Так же можно использовать debuild:

```
debuild -a armhf
```

Для успешной сборки этого может быть недостаточно. Необходимо указать правильный компилятор. Для этого можно использовать переменную окружения *CC*. Как я подсмотрел в модуле `/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm` и программе `dh_strip`, для определения префикса утилит компиляции используется переменная окружения *DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE*, если она отличается от *DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE*, в противном случае префикс не используется. Значит нам нужно поместить либо в `debian/rules` либо в `Makefile` первого уровня строку:

```
export CC=$(DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)-gcc
```

Аналогично для C++:

```
export CXX=$(DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)-g++
```

Если в процессе сборки нужен родной компилятор для компиляции какого-нибудь препроцессора и т.п., нужно вернуть переменную в старое состояние (gcc/g++) для конкретных файлов или каталогов. Если пакет использует qmake, cmake или autoconf, всё это должно делаться автоматически, но не всегда работает.

Отдельного рассмотрения стоит кросскомпиляция библиотек и зависимых пакетов.

#### Зависимости при сборке

`dpkg-buildpackage` и более высокоуровневые утилиты сборки проверяют зависимости указанные в строке **Build-Depends:** файла *debian/control*, что в прочем можно отключить опцией `-d`.

Чтобы пакет удовлетворил зависимость, он либо должен быть архитектуронезависимым (**`Architecture: all`**), либо совпадающей архитектуры (что подходит для библиотек и не подходит, если в процессе сборки необходимо выполнить его бинарный файл), либо иметь свойство **`Multi-Arch: foreign`**, которое должно быть в его файле *control*. Возможен так же более сложный вариант, который используется для интерпретаторов с плагинами в виде динамически загружаемых библиотек как perl или python: в зависимом пакете в `Build-Depends` после имени пакета добавляется **`:any`**, а в удовлетворяющем зависимость пишется строка **`Multi-Arch: allowed`**.

Последний способ позволяет предъявлять два варианта требований к пакету: без `:any` - требуется "своя" архитектура (собираемся связывать свою программу с файлом из этого пакета, например используем свой плагин) - для кросс-сборки скорее всего не подойдёт, так как такие пакеты не могут устанавливаться одновременно двух архитектур, этот вариант обычно используют в зависимостях при установке; с `:any` - любая (просто собираемся запускать интерпретатор).

Кроме `:any` в зависимостях ещё возможен суффикс **`:native`**, означающий что требуется пакет архитектуры, на которой производится сборка (билдера). Этот суффикс почему-то не удовлетворяют пакеты с `Multi-Arch: foreign` или `Architecture: all`, подойдёт пакет без `Multi-Arch`, либо с `Multi-Arch: same` или `Multi-Arch: allowed`.

#### Библиотеки

Если ваш собираемый пакет использует библиотеку, лучший вариант если её пакет имеет свойство **`Multi-Arch: same`**. Это означает, что можно будет установить одинаковые пакеты одновременно под несколько разных архитектур. Файлы библиотек в таких пакетах находятся в разных каталогах в зависимости от архитектуры.
Т.е. вместо старого пути `/lib/` используется `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` или `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`. Имена этих подкаталогов при сборке пакетов библиотек должны браться из переменной *DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH* (которая может отличаться от *DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE*). Остальные файлы могут совпадать, но должны в таком случае быть идентичны. *Версии устанавливаемых пакетов так же должны быть одинаковы*.
В зависимом пакете в `Build-Depends` просто указывается имя библиотечного пакета.

В противном случае требуемая библиотека чужой архитектуры при установке заменяет собой родную библиотеку, что приводит к удалению всех зависимых пакетов родной архитектуры.

Если вы используете для сборки `dpkg-buildpackage` (или более высокоуровневую утилиту), переменные *DEB_...* определяются автоматически. Если вы вызываете `fakeroot debian/rules binary` напрямую, эти переменные не определены. Узнать их стандартнтые значения для вашей системы можно с помощью команд:

```
dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH
dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE
```

А для другой архитектуры добавив опцию `-a`, например `-a armhf`.

#### Установка библиотек чужой архитектуры

При установке появляются две проблемы: библиотека не адаптирована к многоархитектурности, или в репозиториях для разных архитектур последние версии библиотек различаются. Во втором случае `apt-get` выдаёт ошибку типа "битые пакеты" или как и в первом предлагает удалить из системы много нужных пакетов. В первом случае нужно переделать пакет, как описано выше, во втором может помочь понижение версии, т.е. явно указать версию пакета, которая есть для обеих архитектур, например:

```
# apt-get install linux-libc-dev:armhf=3.19.0-68.76 linux-libc-dev:i386=3.19.0-68.76
```