# На Linux собрать пакет, что бы запустить его без установки

Tags: linux

Подскажите, как собрать установочный пакет со всеми зависимостями на Linux? Что бы можно было скопировать его на другую Linux машину и просто его там запустить.

Речь идёт об Iperf. У нас есть роутер с прошивкой Tomato, там Linux 2.6.36.4brcmarm, но установить стандартным путём туда нельзя.

Comment: кросс-компиляция — тема очень и очень обширная (потому вопрос, конечно, подлежит закрытию). в качестве стартовой точки для хоть какого-то понимания, за что вы берётесь, можно взять, например, [википедийную статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но прошу не закрывать тему, или подскажите, как её изменить, что бы она смогла остаться. Возможно кто то сможет помочь советом, или ссылкой. Пока не знаю где ещё можно обратится с таким вопросом. Пусть хотя бы неделю провисит.

Comment: 1. основную модерацию здесь осуществляют сами пользователи (у которых достаточный для этого уровень репутации) **совместно**. 2. собственно кросс-компиляция (само по себе весьма обширное явление) в вашем случае усугубляется тем, что вы хотите собрать бинарники, которые смогут работать с **очень** древними версиями библиотек. а для сборки таких бинарников **обязательно** потребуются очень древние версии компилятора и binutils-ов. вот это всё в совокупности превращает (возможный) ответ на ваш глобальный вопрос в совершенно невписывающийся в формат этого сайта толстый талмуд. увы.

Comment: направление для изучения вы, надеюсь, получили, дальше уже сами действуйте, возвращаясь сюда при необходимости, но с более конкретными вопросами.

Comment: Для Debian см. мой вопрос и ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509878/130

Answer (score 1):

есть неплохая вводная статья: [Introduction to cross-compiling for Linux](https://landley.net/writing/docs/cross-compiling.html).

я здесь основные моменты приведу, чтобы вопрос, хотя он фактически и подлежит закрытию как слишком общий, всё-таки был хоть чуть-чуть полезен.

---

*конспект в работе, не голосуйте за удаление этого ответа, пожалуйста.*

Comment: Голосую за, чтобы подбодрить в этом нелегком деле.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, как собрать установочный пакет со всеми зависимостями на
>   Linux?

Насколько я понял постановку задачи, Ваш вопрос, на самом деле, распадается на два:

1. Как выполнить кросс-компиляцию?
2. Как из полученных модулей собрать пакет.

Как уже говорил  aleksandr barakin, первый вопрос - достаточно тухлый. Я много шишек набил, пока разобрался, что к чему. И тут есть два варианта:

- Воспользоваться средством CrossTool-NG. Эта штука очень универсальная и поэтому, довольно сложная в настройке. Но зато - может всё.
- Воспользоваться набором кросс-компиллеров, входящих в Ваш дистрибутив. Их достаточно много, на разные архитектуры. Во всяком случае PowerPC и ARM - точно есть. Тут всё очень просто: устанавливаете пакеты, для cMake пишите крохотный файл toolchane.txt в котором указывает Ваши компиллеры, а остальное всё уже не Ваша забота.

По CrossTool-NG я даже делал перевод user-guide, могу Вам прислать, если интересно.

По второму пункту есть одна очень серьёзная проблема: кросс-компиллер должен создавать модули для именно той версии ОС, что на целевой платформе. А для этого у вас должны быть все объектники и возможность согласования ABI. По простому: я компилирую на x86 для PowerPC, но версии библиотек должны быть одни и теже, что на исходной, что на целевой.

Второй Ваш вопрос тоже неоднозначный. Какой пакет Вам нужен - rpm или deb ? Хотя идеологически они похожи, но всё-таки собираются по разным методам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уже успел попробовать hndtools-arm-linux. Но пока без результата.